# How to exclude hostnames in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm very unfamiliar with perl syntax and am trying to amend an existing script to exclude a specific hostname from the results.

The hostnames are:

```
router-<something>
switch-<something>
```

I'd like to exclude all results that begin with "router" from the results.

This line in the existing script states:

```
    # These are hosts that we don't want to alert about.
    my %exclude_hosts = map { $_ => 1 } split(',', $exclude_hosts || '');
```

So two questions:

1. Im trying to understand what "map" does in perl and what `map { $_ => 1 }`specifically does
2. How would I insert logic into that statement to exclude all hosts that begin with "router"?

Comment: `map` is something your Perl reference book should be able to explain. Barring that, [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is a documented function.

Comment: `map` in Perl does almost the same as in other languages - applies a function/expression on each element of collection.

Comment: *all results that begin with "router"* is not *a specific hostname*. You need to look at how `%exclude_hosts` is used.

Answer (score 1):

That line builds a look-up table, where for each host there is a trivial (`1`) entry.

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) builtin takes a list and generates the output list by running the code in the block for each element, available in the [special variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_) `$_`. The return of the last evaluated statement in the block for each element, what may be one or multiple scalars (or none), is flattened into the list that is eventually returned.

Here you get a pair for each element, the element itself `$_` and `1` (the [`=>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) is a `,` that quotes its left-hand side operand). An even-sized list can be assigned to a hash (dictionary), whereby successive elements become key-value pairs. So each host (in `$_`) becomes a key, with a value `1`.

Then, to exclude an element either filter the list given to the `map`
using [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

```
my %exclude_hosts = 
    map { $_ => 1 } 
    grep { not /^router/ } 
    split(',', $exclude_hosts || '');
```

or do this in `map` itself

```
my %exclude_hosts = 
    map { (not /^router/) ? $_ => 1 : () } 
    split(',', $exclude_hosts || '');
```

where the empty list `()` gets flattened in the `map`'s returned list, thus vanishing.

Please see the linked documentation for more detail.